# "NEMA 1-15 & 14-50 in same faceplate

Tags: electrical, socket

Looking to install two outdoor sockets for charging an upcoming EV purchase, and if I am to put conduit in for running the extra wires, also to make it easier to power outdoor appliances than running a cord through a window.

I have decided on a NEMA 14-50 socket for EV charging, and I have found that the regular household socket is technically a NEMA 1-15. What I am struggling to find is a mount (am sure there is a technical term for this that isn't "faceplate") that would hold both something like [this](http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/public/en/wiring_devices/products/receptacles/power_receptacles/_50a/power_receptacles_50a_125_250v_nema_14_50_3_pole_4_wire_1258_5754n_1212_58.html) and a regular household power socket a.k.a NEMA 1-15. Is one not made with this configuration? Not opposed to separate mounting, just that would require more space and another security/weather cover.

Comment: Eh? Where'd you get NEMA 1 from? Don't you mean a NEMA 5?

Comment: Maybe they're old school :)

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://www.houzz.com/photos/53554463/60A-Rv-Power-Oulet-With-2-Breakers-industrial-switches-and-outlets)?

Comment: [threephaseeel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/27099) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector#NEMA_1 . From this page, seems NEMA 5-* is the grounded version of NEMA 1-*

Comment: [michael-sqlbot](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/43560) - Sorry, no, just looking for a single NEMA 1/5-15 and the NEMA 14-50 without the breakers.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a problem.  Anything large like this gets put together like Lego.

First you get a multiple gang box.

Then you fit a duplex NEMA 5-15 yoke in one position and the 14-50 yoke in the other position.

Then you go get a faceplate that has openings for a duplex receptacle and also a large opening for a large socket.  These faceplates are the key to it, they are readily available at a *real* electrical supply house, your local big-box not so much.

All the large connectors - NEMA anything-30 or -50 - are of a standard size and use the same faceplate.

You may need to work backwards, find the faceplate first, figure out how many gang box you need, then position the receptacles to match the faceplate.